# dplyr::filter() does not produce the expected output

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Please, find my data `p` below.

I cannot figure out why `filter()` does not work. I want to filter `p$treatment` not equal to `SSTR` but `p$who %in% 1:3`.

```
> table(p$who)

 1  2  3  4 
97 71 96 26 

#and 

> table(p$treatment)

   SSTR     SSA Control 
    119     131      40
```

I have applied

```
p.ssa <- p %>% filter(!treatment=="SSTR",
                     who %in% 1:3)
```

But I still get

```
> table(p.ssa$who)

 1  2  3  4 
53 40 78  0 

# and

> table(p.ssa$treatment)

   SSTR     SSA Control 
      0     131      40
```

The expected output should be

```
> table(p.ssa$who)

     1  2  3  
    53 40 78  

> table(p.ssa$treatment)

   SSA Control 
   131      40
```

My data

```
    p <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("SSTR", 
    "SSA", "Control"), class = "factor"), who = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -290L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `droplevels` to drop unused factor levels in the data.

```
p.ssa <- p %>% filter(treatment !="SSTR",who %in% 1:3) %>% droplevels()

table(p.ssa$who)
# 1  2  3 
#53 40 78 

table(p.ssa$treatment)
#SSA Control 
#131      40
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
p.ssa <- droplevels(setDT(p)[treatment != "SSTR" & who %in% 1:3])
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
p.ssa <- droplevels(subset(p, treatment != "SSTR" & who %in% 1:3))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun. Very nice, I did not knew the `data.table`-approach. Thank you!